# st="hello"; in c-compiler its showing an error require Lvalue what it mean why this error seems to arise

Tags: c

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char st[10],*sr[10];
    st="hiiii";
    sr="gdfsdfsd";
    printf("%s  %s",st,sr);

    return 0;
}
```

This program showing error as Lvalue required.

Is anyone can explain in detail or share me link where i can learn more thanks in advance?

Comment: thankyou but i don't need alternates but i need to know why exactly the error is arising

Comment: or `char st[]="hiiii"`

Comment: thankyou i know this will work but i want to know why the other one is not working i want the details of what causing this error

Comment: `st` is not an `lvalue` because it cannot be assigned to directly. `st` is an array. You cannot assign to an array globally, only by subscripting with `[]`

Comment: The variable `st`'s value will always be the contents of the 10 character array. This cannot be changed. So putting `st` on the left side of an `=` makes no logical sense. It's value is, and always will be, that array. That cannot be changed. You can change the contents of the array, but not the value of `st`, which will always be the array, whatever its contents.

Answer (score 2):

From [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues):

> An lvalue (so-called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a function or an object.

You're trying to assign something to an array (declared like `type x[dimension];`).

C language doesn't allow that. Hence, arrays cannot be lvalues, which explains the compiler error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign something to an array type, we can say that an array is not a left-value (the value that receives the assignment).
There is a special case, you can assign to an array when you declare it, but not after that.

```
char array[] = "hello world"; // OK
array = "nop it doesn't work"; // KO
```

The only way to assign to an array after its declaration, is to copy the values into the array :

```
strcpy(array, "yeah it works");
```

Note that,

```
char array[];
array++;
```

obviously does not work, because it's the same thing as

```
array = array + 1
```

Always remember that arrays are not pointers.